# Local notification flutter periodic notification

Tags: ios, flutter, localnotification

Hi I am developing an app in which I implemented local notification using 'flutter_local_notifications' plugin. how can I schedule notification for repeated interval example 1hr 15min or 2hr 30min like that using   "flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow" this method Flutter (IOS).

Comment: Please elaborate your question and add a few glimpses of your code, so that it is easier to follow up. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: check this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#ios-only-periodic-notifications-showing-up-after-reinstallation

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this?